# Find all k combination length of n elements

Tags: python, list, tree

Hey im trying to find all k combination length of n elements with recursion without using any module

For example `n = 4` so `[0,1,2,3]` and `k=3` so the all the combination length 3 are

```
>>>[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,3],[0,0,4],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2]....
```

I tried to think on that like a tree but i didn't mange to go from here `[0,0,4]` for example to here `[0,1,0]` all i got was `[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,3],[0,0,4]`

Comment: you need to implement using custom function without using `itertools.product` in python?

Comment: without using itertools or any other moudle

Comment: have a look at the docs, it includes the code snippet exactly doing what you want https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: The function I need to implement  must be recursive so what you sent works, but its not the soultion im looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve the bare minimum by using simple recursion.

```py
def combination(n, k):
    if not k:
        return [[]]
    res = []
    nums = list(range(n + 1))
    for comb in combination(n, k - 1):
        for num in nums:
            comb_copy = comb.copy()
            comb_copy.append(num)
            res.append(comb_copy)
    return res
```

Let's take a look at how this code works. First, as with any recursion problem, we establish the base case, which is when `k == 0`. In this case, we would return an empty nested list.

If `k != 0`, then we need to perform recursion. The gist of this problem is that we need to append some numbers to the result returned by `combination(n, k - 1)`. For example, let's say we want to obtain the result for `combination(2, 2)`. The result returned by `combination(2, 1)` would be

```
>>> combination(2, 1)
[[0], [1], [2]]
```

Given this information, how can we get `combination(2, 2)`? For some intuition, here is the result we want:

```
>>> combination(2, 2)
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Observe that all we need to do is to append the values `0`, `1`, and `2` to each element of `combination(3, 1)`. In other words, take the first element, `[0]`. We append `0`, `1`, and `2` to this list, which results in `[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]`. These are the first three elements of `combination(3, 2)`.

Back to the code, we first call `combination(n, k - 1)`, and append `num` to each list in the nested list returned by that function call. Finally, when the appending is over, we return `res`.

One fine detail here is that we create a copy of the list instead of appending to it directly. We do this in order to prevent modifying the original `comb`.

Here is the function in action with `n = 4`, `k = 3`:

```
>>> combination(4, 3)
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 4], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2], [0, 3, 3], [0, 3, 4], [0, 4, 0], [0, 4, 1], [0, 4, 2], [0, 4, 3], [0, 4, 4], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 3], [1, 0, 4], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 0], [1, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 0], [1, 4, 1], [1, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3], [1, 4, 4], [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2], [2, 0, 3], [2, 0, 4], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 4], [2, 3, 0], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 0], [2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 2], [2, 4, 3], [2, 4, 4], [3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 1], [3, 0, 2], [3, 0, 3], [3, 0, 4], [3, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 3], [3, 1, 4], [3, 2, 0], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 4], [3, 3, 0], [3, 3, 1], [3, 3, 2], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 4], [3, 4, 0], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 2], [3, 4, 3], [3, 4, 4], [4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 1], [4, 0, 2], [4, 0, 3], [4, 0, 4], [4, 1, 0], [4, 1, 1], [4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 3], [4, 1, 4], [4, 2, 0], [4, 2, 1], [4, 2, 2], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 4], [4, 3, 0], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2], [4, 3, 3], [4, 3, 4], [4, 4, 0], [4, 4, 1], [4, 4, 2], [4, 4, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

Note that we can get fancier here by implementing things like dynamic programming, but is an optimization detail you might want to consider later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations`

```
import itertools
itertools.combinations('ABCD', 2)
```